# How to remove white space between two characters from a line from text file

Tags: java, string, whitespace

I have a string like below as a line in a text file

`Fri Oct 23 09:59:04.975 CDT 2015 - default-      WHITESPACE  -`

`Fri Oct 23 09:59:04.975 CDT 2015 - default-              -187891074:`

I want to remove the whitespace between `default-` and `-` OR `a random number`. Look at the second line. `default-` is at a fixed position, but second `-` doesn't have fixed position in file.

This is what i have been trying till now

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("output.txt");
String line

while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
   if(line.contains("default-")) {

   }
}
```

Expected output

```
Fri Oct 23 09:59:04.975 CDT 2015 - default--187891074:
```

Comment: What is your **exact** expected output?

Comment: Is the `-` that comes before the number the last `-` in the line?

Comment: @Saviour - Yes it is the last dash and there will be number after that

Comment: In your if statement, you could try `line = line.substring(0, line.indexOf("default-")+8) + line.substring(line.lastIndexOf('-'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`String.replaceFirst()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

```
line = line.replaceFirst("(default-) +(-|\\d)", "$1$2");
```

Comment: @SaviourSelf `Replaces the first substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement. `  More details are in the documentation (linked from my answer).

Comment: I think @SaviourSelf wanted to tell you, that you should include some explanation of your regex in the answer (I agree btw).

Comment: @dsh Right, I was unfamiliar with the \d \1 and \2. Since, you've changed the \1 and \2 to $1$2. What does the \d and $1$2 do?

Comment: @SaviourSelf Here is the syntax: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: @user1803551 Ahh, so \d means a decimal number, and $1 represents the string up to the "default-", and $2 represents anything before a `-` which could be followed by a decimal number. Did I read that right?

Comment: @SaviourSelf Yes. The `\d` is a character class, and the `$1` and `$2` are backreferences to the capture groups.  (I originally wrote `\1` as is used in other tools such as vim, sed, and others then corrected it for Java)

Comment: @yogsma I tested it with the input from your question and it did remove the specified whitespace. Can you elaborate on *This doesn't work.*?

Comment: First it complains about illegal character '\' and then it only does for line 1, never goes on to line two despite i have a while clause.

Comment: when I changed '\' to '/' , it worked on certain lines. Some lines don't have -8393939 number, but something like this 4545445 ..so no '-' and that's where it didn't do anything

Comment: Since the data did not contain a forward slash followed by a d, changing the pattern to match that is not expected to work. I did overlook the need to escape the backslash for the compiler so that the string will contain the backslash in the regular expression pattern.